# How to avoid accidentally generating a float from a long

Tags: stata

The practical problem I've experienced in a nutshell is that I start with some SSNs (Social Security Numbers) stored as `long` integers and then `generate` variables from those.  But if I don't think about it and fail to specify `long` for the new variable, Stata defaults to creating a `float` rather than a `double` or `long`, thus losing the data contained in the SSN.

For concreteness, I'm using an American-style SSN specifically as these have 9 digits.  But as best I can tell this is a problem for any ID variable with 7 or more digits (i.e. whatever is the precision of the mantissa for a Stata `float` variable).

Obviously, I can avoid this by specifying `long`, but it doesn't seem like correct behavior by Stata to lose information like this.  For example, `compress` is too smart to do something like this.  I'm using version 12.1 below.  I'm sure this question has been asked but I haven't been able to find anything here or via Google.

```
. generate long ssn = uniform() * 1e9

. generate ssn_copy = ssn

. format ssn_copy %10.0f

. clist

              ssn    ssn_copy
  1.     58066154    58066152
  2.    675948726   675948736
  3.    715280476   715280448

. describe

ssn             long   %12.0g                 
ssn_copy        float  %10.0f
```

**Edit to add**:  @NickCox mentioned using strings as identifiers.  I tried that and interestingly Stata is smart enough there to generate a string automatically from another string variable.  I like that behavior but it seems inconsistent with the documentation that says float is the default.  It seems that what (in theory) should happen here is that Stata would raise an exception if I try to create a variable from a string without specifying it is a string.

Stata `insheet` is also smart enough to read in a 9 digit number as a long rather than float, so I'm not sure it can even be said that `generate` is consistent with other Stata commands like `insheet`.

Also, while I don't see a problem with using a string to store an ID variable (besides being memory inefficient), I also don't see any problem with using integers for this.

Comment: `clist` is dated. `list` is the preferred command.

Comment: ... from Stata 8 and up, at least.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Yes, and I have hated `list` since version 8. ;-)  Also sticking with `chelp`.

Comment: The contention seems to be that Stata should be smart on your behalf at copying the storage type from what is supplied as an expression to what is created as a new variable. But there are many problems in which there is no association at all, e.g. generating indicator variables (1 or 0) from all sorts of expressions, which might include one or more of  variables that might be `float`. `int`, `long` or `double`. Stata puts the responsibility on the programmer or user, unless as pointed out you use  `clonevar` or spell out the type.

Comment: @NickCox I wouldn't say smart, merely non-lossy in the same way that `compress` is non-lossy.

Comment: You can have a default variable type of `double` if you wish. The StataCorp line is that most of the time that would just waste storage on unnecessary precision, and (as you indicate elsewhere in the thread) being prudent about storage is important too. The problem is that Stata has no way to recognise automatically when every bit really is important (identifiers are the case in point) and when using `double`s would be just holding useless extra detail.

Comment: More personally, while I tend to agree with the StataCorp line, I did my bit for this problem by first writing `clonevar`.

Comment: @NickCox  Thanks, I appreciate the points (and `clonevar`!).  This is getting tangential but it seems like a better (but still simple) approach would be to automatically check the right hand side and then *default* to a non-lossy or least-lossy type.  `compress` already is doing essentially the same thing.  I guess I'm just saying that the default ought to be safety, not compact storage.

Comment: @NickCox  Also note, `insheet` is smart enough to read a 9-digit ID in as a long.  So with commands like `compress` and `insheet` Stata is clearly smart enough to do the safe and non-lossy thing.  I really don't think `generate` has consistent behavior relative to those commands and probably others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default is `float`. This is a much debated topic (specially at www.statalist.com) that divides the Stata community. From [[U] 12.2.2
Numeric storage types](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u12.pdf#u12.2.2):

> Numbers can be stored in one of five variable types: byte, int, long,
>   float (the default), or double. bytes are, naturally, stored in 1
>   byte.

For now, it's up to the user to take care information is not lost due to this "feature".

Another reference is

http://blog.stata.com/tag/precision/,

and you can find a few posts on the subject interspersed at Statalist.

See `help clonevar` to make a copy that will respect the original variable's storage type. For example:

```
clear
set more off

// original
gen long myvar = 1

// "unexpected"
gen myvar2 = myvar

// "expected"
clonevar myvar3 = myvar

describe
```

Comment: Yeah, I mean, I understand all of this as you can hopefully tell from the question. The part I'm interested in, and that you seem to be confirming is that this is somehow expected behavior in the past and continuing to the present. I was hoping the answer was "oh yeah, this was fixed in version14" or something positive like that. Honestly it kind of blows my mind that anyone would argue in favor of this behavior, but if you have links to recent discussion about this on statalist I'd be interested to see those (I expected they existed but haven't been able to locate them).  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the `clonevar` mention btw, that's good to know.  Also makes me wonder why that wouldn't just be an option or default of `generate` rather than a separate command but I clearly am not on the same page with the Stata devs.  ;-)

Comment: Some people think there's nothing to be fixed. I don't really have a strong opinion on this,  but am slightly tilted towards your side. I've read similar complaints about `sort`; in that it should be stable by default. This,  I'm totally against,  but opinions vary. I do think there's a stronger case for the latter. I'll post some links if I I have time to search for them.

Comment: LOL, non-stable sorting is my main other Stata gripe.  I'll check the box and +1 but if you are able to find the links later on I'd appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: There are several interacting issues here. One is that although Stata has its default default, i.e. new numeric variables are `generate`d as `float` without an explicit variable type, you can `set type` otherwise. More specifically, I'd advise holding identifiers as strings anyway. It is hard to see that arithmetic on identifiers makes much sense, but perhaps you are being bitten with other kinds of variables.

Comment: SSN may not be intelligible internationally. Social Security Number?

Comment: @NickCox Yes, Social Security Number (I edited that in).  It's a fair point about strings, although I don't see the harm in using an integer for an identifier, and obviously ints are much more memory efficient.

Comment: A four-digit numeric identifier could be held accurately in an `int` requiring 2 bytes, whereas a `str4` requires 4 bytes. I take it this is the kind of point you have in mind. Independently of that, I have seen many cases in which users managed to do meaningless numeric calculations with identifiers and somehow then tried to make sense of the results.   That is the same generic issue as here: what is the user's responsibility (or the user's problem) when there is scope to do (very) silly things, and what should Stata prevent them from doing (or make more difficult)?

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Also note, `insheet` is smart enough to read a 9-digit ID in as a long.  So with commands like `compress` and `insheet` Stata is clearly smart enough to do the safe and non-lossy thing.  I really don't think `generate` has consistent behavior relative to those commands and probably others.